sessionIDManagerType being ignored
In theory it looks simple: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.createsessionid?view=netframework-4.8.1
I tried to use the example above to prepare custom session id generator, but it's completely ignored. My class:
public class GuidAuthSessionIdManager : SessionIDManager
{
    public override string CreateSessionID(HttpContext context) => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public override bool Validate(string id) => Guid.TryParse(id, out _);
}

and my config:
<sessionState regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"
              sessionIDManagerType="WebApp.Helpers.GuidAuthSessionIdManager, WebApp" />

but debugger does not enter any of methods above and the cookie value still looks like mawfpkqlrsh2emx4dtuozr2l
Any ideas?
I tried all naming combinations of the type:
WebApp.Helpers.GuidAuthSessionIdManager, WebApp

WebApp.Helpers.GuidAuthSessionIdManager

GuidAuthSessionIdManager


Maybe you have different web.config for production and development and it is use the one where u don't have sessionIDManagerType setup.

nope, the only parts of system.web section that are transformed by xsd are
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(requireSSL)"/> and
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

Do u have have it also defined in ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.validate?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Web_SessionState_SessionIDManager_Validate_System_String_

no, it was not defined there, but adding an entry to httpModules didn't fix the issue

silly me, we have overriden the default session behaviour in <system.webServer>/ by  . Thanks @DA for your comments, I would not check modules without your hints
